# How to sync linux time with that of the network on phones?

Tags: android, linux, timezone, embedded

Im facing a problem with images clicked by the camera. When these images are accessed on PC the time reflected in their properties corresponds to that of linux and not of the network (which are unfortunately showing 2 different times). I'm assuming that if the linux time is syncd with the network then this issue will be solved. 
Any ideas as to how the time may be syncd? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is: NTP, Network Time Protocol.

ntpdate will run it once at boot time to set up your time according to NTP server.
ntp is a server daemon!

Maybe you are interested into:

- [The NTP FAQ and HOWTO](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-a-faq.htm)
- [cluster of timeservers](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/)
- [The NTP Public Services Project](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome)

For Debian Users:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ntp ntpdate ntp-doc
```

Answer (score 1):

The protocol commonly used in linux to sync clock is "ntp". There is a commandline tools to run on many linux distribution called "ntpdate" that needs the ntp server as parameter. This mean that if your networks has an ntp server you can sync the clock of your pc with that server or sync both the network and your pc with an external free ntp server (there are many available).